# Forced to have footer div inside fixed width containing <div>. is it possible to keep it there and extend the footer 100% of the body?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to customize the layout of a shopping cart (Infusionsoft) and it forces the editable footer area to be within a footer div which inside a fixed width containing `<div>`. Is it possible to keep it there and though css extend the footer 100% of the body? So basically break the parents div's specified width? Even though the footer is within the fixed width div?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: You could override the parent div's width, or make the position of the footer absolute.

Comment: If I make the #footer width larger than the parents #container div's width, the footer is still constrained to the parents width (so that didn't work). And absolute positioning still is relationship to it's parent div #container which has positioning applied. So that does not work.

Comment: Why can't you change the container's CSS? I mean, you can change the footer's, so you do have access to a stylesheet.

Comment: if I make the container larger than 960px for example 100%.. my #mainContent and #aside float off to the far edges (left and right). Do I correct that with padding?

Comment: The solution depends on the exact css for the container. E.G. does it have `position: absolute` or `relative`. So can you edit the post and put that in?

Comment: I ended up using a jQuery('body').append("<div id='footerDerm'>); to add a footer div using jquery. solved the problem. Thanks to those who replied.